# DDD - Modelling a system of groups and users

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, .net, aggregate

I'm looking for some advice on a system I'm designing, at its core it will allow users to create/join/manage groups of users.

I thought it would be a good idea to try and apply some DDD principles, which has led me to create following domain models, I'm currently treating a **Group** as the aggregate root.

```
public class Group
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Membership
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid GroupID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

*You'll notice I don't have the concept of a 'User' in this system, and that is because users are managed by a different system altogether (it won't be possible to 'merge' the two systems either). I've also simplified the models here for the sake of brevity.*

There are a few concerns I have with this approach and how I'm going to tackle some of the domain invariants:

1. Hydrating a **Group** from the repository will require loading in all of the **Membership** entities, of which there could be many (the maximum will be 1000), this seems a bit ugly however a **Membership** can't exist outside the concept of a **Group** so I don't think it's a candidate to an AR.
2. There is an invariant that limits the number of **Groups** a user can belong to (currently 50). I've seen other examples where the suggestion was to query a count from the repository before persisting the change, but this would introduce a race condition since the system will be used concurrently.
3. I could indeed model **Membership** as its own AR, and then have a MembershipCount property on each **Group** (to satisfy the maximum **Membership** invariant), but this would mean updating two ARs in a single transaction (one to add a **Membership**, and one to increment the MembershipCount on the **Group**). This approach also seems like to could introduce a fair amount of contention if using something like optimistic concurrency control if multiple users are attempting to join the same **Group**.
4. Users cannot join 'Closed' **Groups**. This invariant would be straightforward to satisfy if **Memberships** were a collection inside **Group**, because we could rely on OCC if a **Group** has been closed whilst adding a new **Membership**.

I understand there's likely to be some trade-offs that need to be made here, I don't think it's possible satisfy all of these invariants whilst maintaining complete consistency, but It'd be great to hear any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Group` is an aggregate root. `Membership` make only sense in relation to the group, and should therefore belong to that aggregate, that will have to enforce the invariants related to the group memberships, such as denying adding memberships to closed groups.

Technically,  the hydration of the `Group` does not require all its `Membership`s to be in memory.  You could implement a [lazy load](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) for the `Membership`s.

For practical reasons, you'll probably need a `User` in your model as well, that acts as proxy for the `User` managed in the other system. The `User` would be root of its own aggregate, because `User` exists independently of the the `Group` and should be accessible directly without passing through the aggregate root.

Your narrative suggest that you need bidirectional navigation: a  `User` would maintain a collection `UserMemberships` to  `Groups` to which it is member.  This aggregate would be responsible to enforce the `User` invariants in your model, such as the limits to the number of groups a user can be member of.

Since adding a user to a group involves two different aggregates,  each being responsible of its own invariants, this operation would be a service in the DDD meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I came to a similar solution after thinking about the problem for a while. 

The only aspect that leaves a bad taste is the proxy User, I wouldn't want consumers of this system to have to explicitly create this 'fake' User, so I thought about having a FindOrCreate method on the repository that would be invoked when the existence of the proxy User is necessary. Perhaps there's a better name for this entity that would communicate it's purpose a bit better.

Comment: I also toyed with the idea of not having the proxy User at all, and instead relying on locking at the database level to enforce the invariant, but that feels like I'm allowing business logic to leak into the persistence layer. E.g. In SQL Server teminology, performing a SELECT with an UPDLOCK over the UserMembership entities. The obvious down-side of this approach is that if I were to switch to a different DB vendor I might not be able to achieve the same consistency guarantees.